# Открытие лога действий пользователей

Tags: сервер, сеть, логирование, формат

Здравствуйте. Имеется некий файл с расширение .flow, в котором, по идее, должен содержаться лог действий пользователей в интернете, снятые с одного сервера. Но вот ума не приложу чем его можно просмотреть. Блокнот не берет, погуглил штуку flow analizer - тоже не берет. Может кто сталкивался с подобным?

Comment: А вы уверены, что там действия пользователей, а не информация о трафике, уж больно NetFlow напомнило. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netflow

Comment: Возможно. Меня тоже Netflow привлекает. Но , как я понял, логи там делаются то в обычных текстовых файлах, то в html страницах. Инструмента, который бы читал .flow не нашел.